# Auto mapper : Mapping two objects Ignoring few properties dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, automapper, entity-framework-5

For update using entity frame work , I have a DTO exposed to user with all properties but few properties are assigned with values.

Example

```
public class Employee 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Datetime CreatedDateTime {get;set;}
   public Datetime UpdatedDateTime {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeDTO  
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [JsonIgnore]
   public Datetime CreatedDateTime {get;set;}
   [JsonIgnore]
  public Datetime UpdatedDateTime {get;set;}
}
```

Now The Dto is been populated

```
EmployeeDto  e = new EmployeeDto ()
{
Id =1,
Name = "xxxxxxxxx" 
}
```

Now we have called the method to update

```
public bool Update(EmployeeDto e )
{
   var repo = _dbset.Employee.Get(x => x.id == e.Id)
   var d = _mapper.Map<Employee,EmployeeDto>(repo,e);  
   _dbset.Employee.UpdateAsync(d);
}
```

**   but here on mapping the Created Date and Update Date are set to default values which is giving  me an SQL exception**

Please do help me in this case . Sorry If I am not clear

Comment: Check this out, you will find couple of ways to do it. https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ignore-using-automapper-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your ModelMappingProfile class, it will ignore the properties you'll specify. You also check this link for understanding.
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ignore-using-automapper-in-csharp/

```cs
CreateMap<EmployeeDTO, Employee>().ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDateTime, opts => opts.Ignore()).ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDateTime, opts => opts.Ignore());
```